# Why do will/didSet trigger initializer error, but not regular set/get?

Tags: swift

This compiles fine:

```
class Foo {
    var number = 0
    var name: String
    init(name: String){ self.name = name }
}

class SubFoo: Foo {
    init(_ x: Int){
        super.init(name: "abc")

    }

    var a: Int {
        set {}
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

`a` is a computed property and thus does not require initialization.

But this does not compile:

```
class SubFoo: Foo {
    init(_ x: Int){
        super.init(name: "abc")

    }

    var a: Int {
        willSet {}
        didSet {
            print(oldValue)
        }
    }
}
```

The SubFoo init method shows this:

> error: property 'self.a' not initialized at super.init call
>           super.init(name: "sdf")

`a` is still not a "real" property, so what exactly is the compiler expecting here?

Strangely I can silence the error by doing this:

```
init(_ x: Int){
    a=0
    super.init(name: "sdf")

}
```

Why would the `a=0` be required for a `willSet` but not a normal `set`?

Comment: `a` is a stored, not computed, property in your second example. `willSet` and `didSet` are merely observers.

Comment: @Hamish that's very interesting, I thought all these property methods were "computed"

Comment: I've always thought this was a design mistake in the syntax. These two look way too similar given the large difference in their functionality. I'd prefer it if the observers were declared separately, or at least not inside brackets.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I entirely agree, I thought everything in the brackets referred to computed, not stored, property behaviors. And the Apple Swift book does not clarify this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `willSet` and `didSet` appear in brackets after the property, similar to computed methods `get` and `set`, they are not referring to a computed property behavior. `willSet` and `didSet` act on stored properties. This is also why you can provide a default value for them, but not for `get/set`:

```
   var a: Int = 6 { // this line would not compile for a computed property
        willSet {
        }
        didSet {
            print(oldValue)
        }
    }
```

This is the reason for the compiler error in the `init` -- there was no initialization of the stored property.